# Duplicate business logic check on Microservices Patterns

Tags: architecture, microservices, messaging

I'm reading now "Microservices Patterns" by Chris Richardson.
At chapter 5 "Designing business logic in a microservice architecture" the author present the Ticket aggregate and its methods.

While reading the "preparing" and "cancel" methods,
I have noticed that there is a state check of the ticket before the event is published.

When the service consume the events it has to verify the state again in a transaction manner using the database, which result a duplicated logic.

For example, if a Ticket is in a ACCEPTED state and both "cancel" and "prepare" methods are called, there would be a race that could only be handled using the db transaction.

I wanted to hear your thoughts on that and verify my understanding.

```java
public List < TicketPreparationStartedEvent > preparing() {
    switch (state) {
        case ACCEPTED:
            this.state = TicketState.PREPARING;
            this.preparingTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
            return singletonList(new TicketPreparationStartedEvent());
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedStateTransitionException(state);
    }
}
public List < TicketDomainEvent > cancel() {
    switch (state) {
        case CREATED:
        case ACCEPTED:
            this.state = TicketState.CANCELLED;
            return singletonList(new TicketCancelled());
        case READY_FOR_PICKUP:
            throw new TicketCannotBeCancelledException();
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedStateTransitionException(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: *When the service consume the events it has to verify the state again in a transaction manner using the database, which result a duplicated logic.* Why? Which service is this, a different one from the one originally publishing the events?

Comment: It might be a different one, but even if not, multiple event messages may be sent simultaneously (both cancel and prepare). So, the author actually answered me and said he would use an optimistic lock on the records.